# Forcing user to update another cell after updating first cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet with a list of sales on it.

When a user sets the "Status" column to "Closed" I want to force them to enter a date in the "Closed Date" column.

So I have this;

```
A1 (Status), B1 (Closed Date)
Open, <blank>
Open, <blank>
Closed, 1/1/2018
```

Comment: You could investigate the Change event but, if you want to force this requirement, BeforeSave is the more likely.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the `Sheet Tab` --> `View code` and paste the code given below into the opened code window and save your workbook as `Macro-Enabled Workbook`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row > 1 Then
    If Target <> "" And LCase(Target.Value) = "closed" Then
        With Target.Offset(0, 1)
            .Select
            On Error Resume Next
            .Comment.Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
            .AddComment.Text "Please enter the Closed Date"
            .Comment.Visible = True
        End With
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Comment.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
ElseIf Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row > 1 Then
    If LCase(Target.Offset(0, -1)) = "closed" And IsDate(Target) Then
        Target.Comment.Delete
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim x
Dim i As Long, lr As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
x = Range("A2:B" & lr)

If Target <> "" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
End If

For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
    If LCase(x(i, 1)) = "closed" And Not IsDate(x(i, 2)) Then
        Cells(i + 1, 2).Select
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```